# How to generate an exectutable file with netbeans 8.2 in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, netbeans, executable

I installed NetBeans 8.2 (but the same is for any version of NetBeans C/C++)  in a linux OS (Linux Mint Ulyssa, which based to what i know is ubuntu core. I can run successfully with the expected result a project (simple "hello world") but can't in the build folder of the project i can't find a file that i can execute in Linux.

What am i missing, what would the extention of the file be in Linux. Doing the same process in windows i can find the *.exe in the build folder but in linux can't find a way to create a single runnable file that i can run on any other Linux OS (of course, on the compatible ones).

Comment: Usually Linux executables have no extensions.

Comment: understood, than the file i see at the build folder might be the one. But still can't run it. When i double click on it a window pops up that asks with which program should i run it. It confuses me even more

Comment: What is the file named in your build folder? Also, when you try to run it from there can you select your terminal? (I have minimal experience with netbeans) 

But you should also be able to run it straight from the terminal. If you navigate into your build folder, then simply ./a.out, might have to use chmod to allow execution.

Comment: @Muderino the project is named test and the file inside the build folder has the same name i tried to run it through terminal but have no result. Actually don't know if i didn't get a result because it isn't working or because the only thing that it does is 
`printf("Hello World")` I suppose it might print hello world in the terminal, am i wrong?

Comment: Could you submit the code in your original post. I mean everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't run netbeans 8.2, but I got a hold of 12.2. And they seem pretty similar.

What I had to do to get the project running was to create the compile (build) command:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

And in run I did:

```
./main
```

This allowed me to run a hello world code example through netbeans. In case you're not familiar with g++ the -o argument allows you to set a output-filename.

The code I ran was a simple "hello world":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understood in your comments you named the file and output test, so you should change that from my example.

I'm not sure if this solved your problem as the initial description was a bit hard to understand. But this is what I gathered from the information you gave.

To make a desktop runable application from your c-program, you can do the following.

If you want it to be executable from the users account make a `<program>.desktop` file and place it in `~/.local/share/applications/<program>.desktop` this will allow the user to execute it witout using a terminal. If you want it to be global then place it inside of `/usr/share/applications`

This is the desktop-file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=xfce4-terminal -e "/PATH/BINARY"
Name=SCRIPTNAME
```

And this is the updated version of hello world, if you don't add the scanf then the program just executes without you noticing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    
    //Keep the program running until input
    char ch;
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Cool, that helped command line `./test` and the output was as expected "Hello World". Is it possible to have a file that by double clicking on it it runs automatically. The one who is going to use it isn't familiar with line command / terminal.

Comment: Updated the answer. To answer your new question.